# How expensive are immutable objects in Android?

Tags: java, android, immutability

Say I want to create a class to represent complex numbers. The object contains only two floats, but of course there are a large number of methods.

```java
class Complex extends Number implements Comparable {

    float mReal, mImaginary;

    public Complex(float r, float i) {
        mReal = r;
        mImaginary = i;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of this
     */
    public void set(float r, float i) {
        mReal = r;
        mImaginary = i;
    }

    /**
     * Add other to this
     */
    public void add(Complex other) {
        mReal += other.mReal;
        mImaginary += other.mImaginary;
    }

    // And so on and so forth
}
```

I know I can make life a lot simpler by making this immutable instead, but that means a lot more object creation and garbage-collecting. Does anybody have an idea of how expensive this creation and destruction will be in Android? (And not just the latest release; I want to support devices running 2.x as well.)

Comment: whether you should worry about this is completely dependent on _where_ and _when_ you create these objects.

Comment: It's a calculator app; numeric objects are constantly being created and destroyed unless I use a mutable class.

Comment: Well, I've decided to go with immutable because it simplifies a lot of things and it's the Right Thing To Do. I'll leave the question open, however, because I'm still curious as to what the cost is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to not worry about this and go ahead and create the app with immutable objects.

> whether you should worry about this is completely dependent on where and when you create these objects

My comment was more aimed at asking if you wanted to do expensive operations at critical points in your app (e.g. during the draw pass). It sounds as though you are not.

Anecdotally, in my experience, using immutable object patterns hasn't made a noticeable impact on memory or performance in apps I've worked on. That is, while there may be an impact, it's never been *the* reason for a noticeable slowdown.

(Admittedly, my professional experience spans from API 14+.)

Comment: I'll switch over and see how it goes.